Would it be possible for a planet to have only one lifeform?
Earth is obvously made up of lifeforms all interacting with each other - could a planet exist that has only one lifeform?  Not one that has wiped out all the others and not one lifeform which has just evolved, which would presumably be microbial. Just a single species of plant-like life with no bacteria, microbes or larger lifeforms present?

Sure, if you want. I'm not seeing a problem for us to solve here.

If evolutionary pressures were non-existent in some early period, the original lifeform or its descendants might easily fill the world in such a way as to leave no niches for anything else. Once sophisticated enough, that lifeform might have an immune system of sorts that destroys mutant/cancers. This seems weird, but remember we only have a single real-world example to compare to, and it may actually be atypical.

It's hard to imagine. But also, anything non-Earth is hard to imagine. Yet, that hasn't really stopped fiction writers from making various beings. Robert Sheckley, in his short story "Hands off", has an alien which is a walking rectangle. 50cm x 30cm and 5cm wide. Is that plausible? Well, doesn't at all impact the story. In fact, the unexpected differences between that being and regular humans is what drives the story forward.

If you're saying the lifeform did not evolve, then it came into existence either through magic or alien technology. In which, do whatever you want

Whoever voted to close this as "Needs More Details..." while it's not obligatory to explain why you cast a close vote, it's a bit of a high expectation to vote that particular reason and not explain what details are missing. I found this Q in the VTC queue - and I'm voting to keep it open. Cheers.

Having said that... please keep in mind @Netiger that the chemistry of life is very broad and robust. The chemistry having come together to form one life makes the idea of it not coming together for another one of those "mathematically possible but in real life impossible" situations. But, does that matter? If you're asking if it's possible our only answer is "Earth proves it's not." If you're asking if it's believable the answer is, "that's a whomping cool worldbuilding idea!" Never let Real Life hold your imagination back!

Define "lifeform". Is a species which undergoes many very different phases (even more complex than larval forms for butterflies, or stationary and mobile phases for corals), a single lifeform? If we stretch the definition enough, we could argue that Earth has only one lifeform: DNA. Everything else is just packaging.

@JohnO: How could you not have selective pressure? I also doubt you could ever have a 100% reliable, 100% exact replication mechanism.

What about prions.  They are sort of alive and perhaps the primordial soup in your world only has ingredients for one type of prion and further evolution is not possible.  xkcd.com/2307

@KalleMP Prions aren't alive, not even a little. They're like heat-seaking dominoes that have been set up, waiting for someone to accidentally kick the first one over.

@Michael It sucks that we only have one life-bearing planet as a real-world example. We can't even look back at our own world and see what things were like a billion years ago, we only get this most recent snapshot. We'll know more once we're out there Star Treking around (in other words, never).

I would suppose that, when life appeared on Earth, there actually was a single lifeform, at least for some time. We don’t know how it happened, and maybe life appeared in different spots independently, but the fact that all modern lifeforms have DNA and RNA is probably a good clue that we all come from a single lifeform as a common ancestor.

In a scifi world, you absolutely can... but if you're trying to be realistic, then evolution isn't optional. Evolution WILL happen, and it WILL cause species to differentiate. The fact that your life-form is complex (plant-like) means it's already gone through a lot of evolution. It's been through many, many stages of development, each more complex, and each stage has to have completely wiped out the previous stage without branching to preserve the single species status. In practice, that's simply not how it works.

The problem with such a lifeform is eating up all its food supply.  Sunlight can be treated as free, but -- assuming photosynthesis, as in terrestrial life, chemistry indicates any alien substitute will have the same issue -- plants will eat up all the carbon dioxide, water, and trace nutrients.  True, they will then metabolize some of what they photosynthesize to live, but most of them remain locked up in the plant body.  Whenever one of the nutrients runs out, the plants will die.
Because there is no organism eating them, their corpses will remain forever.
Either your plant has to be also a herbivore and/or scavenger, eating its fellows and metabolizing their bodies, or else you need fire.  Lots of fire.  Perhaps your world is stormy, and your ocean-living plant is thrown up on land by waves, where it dries out and is struck by lightning.  Once the system is mature, the growth among plants is locked to the rate of fire.  The scavenger route is limited by the rate of death.  Herbivore requires a cycle of switching to eating when nutrients are scarce, but is unlimited thereafter.
There may be other natural processes that can substitute for fire, but they tend to be slower still.

On a geologically active world everything is recycled eventually, but yes this has been an issue a couple of times in our own history, cough great oxidation event cough cough. +1.

@Ash Geological action would serve like fire.  Very, very, very slow fire.

Most plant decomposition on Earth occurs via microbial action, but there are other slower chemical and physical processes that might work given a range of complex chemicals in a dead, plant, oxygen, UV light, water, weathering, lightening and as mentioned geological processes and fire.

Note: Before you have fire, you need something like oxygen in the atmosphere. Typically an oxygen atmosphere is produced by photosynthesizing life. So your species's ancestor needs to have survived a great oxidation event it caused after evolving anaerobically. That's not necessarily a deal-breaker, but it is a challenge since it's generally believed the GOE on earth eliminated most species at the time (although that's somewhat speculative since we have very little evidence for how many species existed two billion years ago).

I actually don't think this is a problem at all. Like you said, the plants are scavengers and/or cannibals. Sure, on earth, the decomposition process is typically handled by microbes, but it doesn't have to be that way. If the forest floor becomes a blanket of dead plants, then the living plants will grow roots into the dead ones and extract what they need. Life can handle this kind of issue. The real problem is that in the process, the adaptive pressure will inevitably cause speciation as different individuals find unique solutions to the changing environment.

You can have lifestages, similar to caterpillars, which devour the corpses. And pheno-types, as in different shapes and lifestyles depending on epigenetic triggers. Finally, a organism moving through different stages, could go back and forth, dissasembling into smaller subparts, that form one new organism.

It would fall apart
I think that this kind of arrangement is arguably unstable by nature. Mainly because, at that scale, you're going to have adaptation. It's simply unrealistic to have global homogeneity unless DNA or the like is somehow perfectly encoded without error. The point being that, with this kind of scale, it's likely that at some point there will be a form of life that takes advantage of the relatively unprotected biomass, and begins to compete with it.
Generally, lower trophic levels of life are constrained by predation while upper trophic levels are constrained by food resources. So basically, anything that can munch on the global lettuce colony is going to immediately become wildly successful until further diversification constrains it, and so on. This is also probably why more abundant ecosystems sustain higher biodiversity, they can realistically accommodate more niches.
There's also the issue of practicality. A planet, by nature, is going to have irregularities in climate. This, if nothing else, means that it's not very realistic for the global biomass to be fully homogeneous, since your average desert lettuce colony, tundra lettuce colony, and swamp lettuce colony are going to have different needs. So it's likely that climate variation would force diversification, which would encourage competition, which would lead to further diversification until a typical trophic pyramid is established. It's conceivable that you could have a dominant species that's just better adapted, but I doubt that the global lettuce colony would last on an evolutionary timescale.
Even ignoring this (especially if you mean a single global organism connected wholly across the entire world), there's the matter of natural selection at the cellular level. Depending, your plant is probably going to get cancer somewhere, which is a lot like natural selection. Random variation may eventually produce cells that are parasitic, and a small number will figure out how to trump existing mitigatory systems in the host. At the global scale I'm sure that this would also occur, although in our present ecosystem there are many cancer resistant organisms, and I assume that this plant cancer could serve as another potential seed for biodiversity.
Anyways, that's my two cents. You could always handwave it, it's your choice, and I suppose if you assume the organism is perfectly competitive and resistant to any cancer, you could maybe make it work. But the other posts should also be considered, like the issue of decomposition, too.

This would be very improbable. The basic function of life is to take energy from the sun or heat from within the planet and using resources, convert that energy into reproduction and living. On earth, plants are very complex and are dependent on the microbes in the soil to convert rock into nutrients. Many plants are dependent on the prior existence of other plants.
Earth geology has a long history of being modified by microbes. We don't know how far deep into the earth's crust microbes and viruses go and what they are doing down there. We do know that microbes have modified earth's atmosphere (so that we could breathe it). Basically, microbes altered earth so that other plants and animals could live on it.
So, your plants have two problems. One is how to collect and use energy. The other is how to convert the planet's rocks into resources to build and operate the internal structures. The latter is complicated by how mineral resources are spread out and may not be available where the plant wants to grow. The mineral resources could be bound up in a rock form that the plant is not able to crack.

Probably no. Anything we would consider "plant-like" (a life-as-we-know-it plant) is a Eukaryote with organelles. In particular Plasids and Mitochondria which both evolved separately were later absorbed into more complex cells and are now found in symbioses. A single organism ecosystem with plant-like complexes, as we understand it, is therefore impossible.
A primary producer like a Cyanobacteria, that undertakes photosynthesis, but huge may be an option but that's not really a plant.

There are ecosystems with only one lifeform. There are extremophile bacteria that live deep underground. There is one  found in deep mines in South Africa that lives off the products of radioactive decay and has been cut off from all other life forms. They did not evolve in isolation, so they once lived with other life forms. They probably adapted to extreme environments to avoid predators, and became isolated.
It might be possible to have the reverse process: to have all life combine into a single organism. Pando is a quaking aspen that has spread by putting out suckers. It is a single organism that weights 6000 tonnes and covers 43 hectares. It contains many species within and around it. So you could extrapolate this, and have some variety of species, but all of them dependent to some degree on one dominant lifeform.

That raises the important question of what you consider a single lifeform or single organism.  I was thinking along similar lines but maybe a step further, if the genome of the parent organism incorporated all the DNA of the organisms that it was dependent on, so it could express whatever function whenever it needed to.

You could do that. But we have absorbed things like gut bacteria which still maintain their separate genetic identity. This means that our gut bacteria population can adjust to local conditions. This is probably a better and more robust way of doing things then controlling everything from top down IMHO.

True but then whether its only one lifeform is questionable.

If you read the paper that first link is based on they say that it is dominated by a single phylotype, not that a single lifeform was recovered, and - indeed - in the link you give they're quoted as saying "Has this one strain of bacteria evolved to possess all the characteristics it needs to survive on its own, or are they working with other species of bacteria?"

Technically, no
A bit pedantic, but the answer to the question as posted is probably "no". You want only one lifeform, and not a freshly evolved microbial one - you want a plant or something, and it should be

Not one that has wiped out all the others

But what did that plant evolve from? Probably some microbial life, right? Well - where is that microbial life now? Probably "wiped out" by the more competetive plant, right?
Actual answer: highly unlikely
But let's put the pedantry aside and assume it's OK for previous evolutionary stages of your one lifeform to have existed and gone extinct.
On earth, we have life evolved to take in one kind of energy and use it. Be that through photosynthesis (using sunlight, like plants), or through burning fuel (consuming organic material, like animals and fungi). The chemical processes form a cycle, where (very simplified) plants take in carbon dioxide, water and sunlight, use the carbon for themselves, and release oxygen. Said oxygen is then used by animals and fungi to burn some of the carbon from plants (and other animals/fungi) with the oxygen, releasing carbon dioxide. Rinse and repeat.
For you to have only one lifeform, and let it survive long-term, it would have to form its own cycle - to use all its own byproducts, otherwise it will poison itself (look up the great oxidation event - earliest life releasing oxygen was quite a problem!).
It would have to evolve - with no side branches, since it's not supposed to have wiped out other forms of life - to use an energy source that does not come from other life and will not run out anytime soon, such as sunlight or warmth from geological processes, with no byproducts. We could imagine that as a plant which uses photosynthesis in one step to build energy stores in carbon form, then when the sun is out (night? winter?) burns that carbon with oxygen much like an animal would. That would only change the atmospheric composition by as much carbon as is stored in the plant's body and energy stores. Oh, and the plants are either immortal or able to cannibalize other plants' bodies when they die, so we don't have dead biomass unused (and messing up our chemical balance).
Possible, but unlikely:

Both paths in one lifeform is far more complex than just one, and thus less likely to happen
Not a single plant (or its predecessors) ever evolved to take advantage of only one part? It would be quite advantageous to only consume other plants' energy stores and not bother photosynthesizing yourself. Without having to build huge leaves, you might even evolve to be mobile and seek out other plants to consume!

Of course, it could still happen
You're writing a story. If you want it to happen, it will.
Naturally
If the plants evolved like that naturally - it's HIGHLY unlikely. But unlikely does not mean "impossible". A coin totally could flip heads ten times in a row, and if the author of the story wants it to, it will. Maybe have your story's characters marvel about how fascinating it is that such an unlikely event has happened. They might also speculate that it was...
Through outside intervention
My first thought if I found a planet with only one lifeform, perfectly balanced to live all on its own? Sure, it COULD have evolved like that, but I feel that it would be actually more likely that intelligent life evolved (there or elsewhere), engineered that plant or found it on a planet it evolved alongside other life, and planted it on this world. So, let's start looking for the gardeners! Other intelligent life to meet, hooray!

It might have arrived by chance (panspermia).

@gerrit panspermia works a lot better for microbial life than for complex plants - might still be possible in theory, but I still would think panspermia of an entire plant and no other lifeforms less likely than "yay, aliens! I hope they're humanoid and maybe even mammals!"

"A coin totally could flip heads ten times in a row" - the odds of that are 1024:1 against. I have no way of calculating the actual odds of evolution starting from pre-biotic chemistry and ending up with only one species of something as highly-evolved and complex as a plant, with no other sidelines or even any form of environmentally-driven speciation but I'd bet real money that the number to the left of the colon would have to be expressed as a very, very large power of ten just to fit on the page :-D  EDIT: I'm worried that looks dismissive; it's not - the answer is excellent.

Reminds me of the Larry Niven short story from 1966 titled "Bordered in Black" where the planets ocean was just one type of algae but one continent was bordered in black.  A slightly macabre story but worth reading.

Although you have ruled out the option of one that has wiped out all others, there might be events that only one species can survive.  This could happen with a species that can survive extreme circumstances, such as tardigrades.  Perhaps an asteroid has struck Earth, with rocks being flung out into space and some of them reaching Mars.  If only one life-form survives this transport, Mars is now a single-species planet.
This situation is unstable, as over time, either speciation would occur due to evolution, or the single lifeform would die out.  But by coincidence, external observers might reach the planet just around the time that indeed only a single lifeform does exist.

Your biggest problem here, I think, is not the ecosystem. Your biggest problem is hypothesising a reproductive system which always creates exact duplicates of itself. Even binary fission has some error rate - and having some kind of error rate is a basic requirement for evolution. No errors, no evolution.
Of course it depends on your definition of "life form", and indeed on your definition of "life". Assuming you're looking for at least a bacterium though, you're not going to get that without evolution.
Of course it might be possible through intelligent design - but not naturally.

Many problems with this I imagine, however most arise from the obvious lack of diversity.
One way around the problem could be solved by allowing its offspring to fill different roles in the food web though its life cycle progression. It could occupy many niches in the environment by exhibiting many different forms throughout its life cycle.
I could be wrong but, especially in an alien ecosystem, I see no reason to have a limit on the number of stages an organism goes through to reach the final or adult form. Most insects go through four: egg, larva, pupa, and adult. This organism could radically change in any number of ways any number of times to fill out voids in the environment.
Indeed it could make an interesting story of discovery that the many apparently completely separate species in the new biome turn out to be a single one.

At this point the aliens are putting into question the definition of "species". Sure, the same seed can grow into a sprawling moss or a towering tree or even a roving carnivore depending on the environment and the stage of its life cycle. But then in what sense are they the same species? The dictionary says they're the same species if they can reproduce with each other - perhaps, but a desert cactus and a tundra grass will never naturally be in a position to fertilise each other, so were they the same species before humans brought them to the lab? There's a lot we don't know!

@ChristopherWells It's possible to define a species from a genetic point of view: individuals with identical DNA, exhibiting different phenotypes because different genes are activated, would clearly be the same species. That still leaves the question of how the species propogates without that DNA drifting, and thus diversifying.

The problem with your idea is that if a single lifeform is also the whole ecosystem, then its only "single lifeform" by a very flimsy definition. Your global blob would have to have cells/cell equivalents of plants, animals, fungi and bacteria, so that it could recycle its own biomatter. These specific cells or tissues would have to be so thoroughly differentiated, that the are essentially different lifeforms, just symbiotic with the system.
Where do you draw a line between: "this is a photosynthetic growth of the global lifeform" and "this is a separate plant that grows on the life-form, symbiotically"?

I don't particularly see why not.
Evolution-wise it would definitely be a little strange, and almost certainly there would have been competing microbial lifeforms at some point, at the very least there would probably have been periods in which there were different competing variants of the same organism, but especially if you have them reproduce aesexually and perhaps give them some kind of horizontal gene transfer, I could definitely envision a colony plant-like organisms surviving perfectly well with no other species.
In the short term (evolutionarily speaking) it could derive all of it's carbon and nutrients from the soil or water if it has filter feeding capabilities, but in the long run, it would definitely have to rely on some kind of indirect cannibalism to obtain nutrients that have already been metabolized. One way I could definitely see this happening is if it had a larval/spore stage in which it broke down the "corpses" of adults, preparing for itself a nutrient rich patch in which to grow and recycling the nutrients consumed by past generations. For energy, it could just preform photosynthesis or chemosynthesis like any real autotroph.


Would it be possible for a planet to have only one lifeform?

Maybe, but it should be a unicellular life form. Why? Because, if we stretch the definitions a little, any complex life form is actually a conglomerate of different kinds of cells. Each kind of cell can be assimilated to a life form - being able to continue its existence only together with the other ones.
Plants live in  tight symbioses with fungi and bacteria, especially at the roots level.
Mammals (and not only) have literally bacterial floras in their guts to continue survival.
And so on.
CONCLUSION: In the conditions set in the question, it can be only a microbe on that planet. The microbe might have evolved, might have been created, or might have been brought - by another life form traveling throughout the universe, or by some mineral carrier (e.g., asteroid).

Yeah, absolutley. Maybe even the way slime molds can be a "single cell" or plasmodial form - "These contain many nuclei without cell membranes between them, and can grow to meters in size." (or bigger in this case).

Absolutely impossible as it fundamentally conflicts with evolution
Evolution has pretty simple requirements: inheritance, mutation, and differential survival. In order for there to be a single species of life on the planet, that species would have to not undergo mutation - because as soon as it does, it will produce variations that are better suited to particular locations on the planet - whether that be differences in soil composition, temperature or whatever. The accumulation of such mutations is what speciation is, and without it the organism cannot evolve in the first place.
And ecologically implausible to boot
All life on Earth exists in the context of other life and cannot survive without it. Animals breathe oxygen produced by plants, and ultimately burn energy produced by them; plants rely on microbes to fix nitrogen from the air, and fungal forms to breakdown the bodies of dead plants and animals into trace elements they can absorb from the soil; and so on. No single organism ever completes all the necessary roles for their survival and they could never evolve to do so, because niche specialisation would always be evolutionary favoured over such generalisation.

The question does not specifically exclude creationism, so your answer is only half true (even though actually correct) :)

@virolino I mean it's tagged "evolution" but obviously if you're accepting magic then anything goes.

Well, I have the unintentional bad habit of not noticing the tags. You are right, "evolution" is there.

Different generations of the same species can replace very different organisms, if such are required by ecology.
Plants follow an evolutionary "two-generation" life cycle in which the first form, the sporophyte, gives rise to the second form, the gametophyte. These two generations can either appear quite similar or differ significantly. In higher plants, the sporophyte is the stage we typically recognize as the "plant," while the gametophyte is reduced to a tiny structure, such as a pollen grain, consisting of only a few cells. In mosses, however, the green leafy structure is the gametophyte, and the sporophyte is a smaller structure consisting of a stalk and capsule that grows from it. In many algae species, such as Ulva, the gametophyte and sporophyte are almost identical in appearance and grow independently.
Rather than having separate specialized species, it is conceivable that a single species could undergo multiple generations, each distinct enough to fulfill different ecological roles. For example, such a species might have plant-like forms and single-celled "microbial" forms that spread widely and assist in decomposing organic material. Such differences in form and function are not difficult to envision.
If two generations are insufficient, some algae exhibit a triphasic life cycle, including haploid, diploid, and tetraploid generations. Incorporating a "fungal" form into this cycle could also be advantageous for decomposition and nutrient cycling.
The question of how such a multi-generational species might end up being the only one in the planet is complex, but it could potentially be introduced from elsewhere—either by chance or through intentional intervention, such as from space.
A multi-generational species has a chance to evolve during ordinary evolution, as it may be beneficial for different generations to take different ecological niches. Existing examples are not that much extreme, but, for instance, in brown algae Laminaria, the sporophyte is the large seaweed that anchors to rocky substrates and forms underwater "forests." The gametophyte is a tiny, microscopic filament that grows in different, often more sheltered areas (e.g., crevices or under other algae). The forms have the potential to start independent evolution.

The general consensus here is that a single organism is unlikely to evolve naturally. Evolution consists of natural variations and natural selection.
Here's how it might happen...
A civilisation explores the nearby stars using very light probes and solar sails. These may be only a few grams. More sophisticated versions may be able to extend themselves using the material they find at their destination.  More sophisticated versions may be able to build any part of themselves. Circuits could be built at the atomic level from carbon, which could control molecular level actuators, with would make MEMS, which could make macroscopic arms and legs. This would not add much to the mass, as all you need to send is the lowest level of the fabrication chain, and the instructions on how to do the rest.
When it arrives, it might use the materials it found to make a transmitter to return data, or another solar sail so it could travel back with the data, or travel on to other stars.
If the thing can build any part of itself, then it can build another one. If you have a planet to survey, it might be sensible to make lots of copies. At this point, the device itself must have a lot of sophistication to be able to evaluate all the necessary strategies, but this is just a copying of the basic instructions.
You then end up with something that is quite life-like, but each entity is the same at its core. Remaining one 'species' (if that is the right word) is a good strategy because it has been designed to explore and thinly populate a barren environment. It never really evolves because any variation in the original core design is likely to be fatally flawed. It may even be designed to error-check itself, and die if flaws are found. But it has the freedom to grow extra arms and legs if resources permit, so it may take many forms.
If it populated a planet with lots of copies of itself, then you may have large numbers and natural selection would start again. But that was not part of the original design, so it would not do that.
It is a sort of panspermia.

No, that is not possible, at least not as a result of evolution.
A planet, by simple laws of physics, is a very diverse place. Some areas are hot while others are cold. Wet or dry. Turbulent or calm. Lit or shaded. Acidic or basic. Filled with or devoid of any number of chemicals. Each point in this multi-dimensional space can be its own ecological niche, and no single organism can specialize to occupy literally every single one of these niches. Random mutations will all but guarantee, given enough time, that all these niches will be filled eventually, adding even more xomplexity through the presence or absence of other organisms.
Even if you start out with a single ancestral lifeform from which all others evolve, the resulting specialists cannot be called "the same lifeform" in any meaningful way.

What's if there's a singular organism? Think Solaris.
We don't know how such arrangement may arise but it's not impossible.
